# MySQL query to assign values to a field based in an iterative manner

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a MySql table with 500,000 records. The table contains a field (abbrevName) which stores a two-character representation of the first two letters on another field, name.

For example AA AB AC and so on.

What I want to achieve is the set the value of another field (pgNo) which stores a value for page number, based on the value of that records abbrevName.

So a record with an abbrevName of 'AA' might get a page number of 1, 'AB' might get a page number of 2, and so on.

The catch is that although multiple records may have the same page number (after all multiple entities might have a name beginning with 'AA'), once the amount of records with the same page number reaches 250, the page number must increment by one. So after 250 'AA' records with a page number of 1, we must assign futher 'AA records with a page number of 2, and so on.

My Pseudocode looks something like this:

```
-Count distinct abbrevNames
-Count distinct abbrevNames with more than 250 records
-For the above abbrevNames count the the sum of each divided by 250
-Output a temporary table sorted by abbrevName
-Use the total number of distinct page numbers with 250 or less records to assign page numbers incrementally
```

I am really struggling to put anything together in a query that comes close to this, can anyone help with my logic or some code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try with this one:

```
SELECT abbrevNames, CAST(pagenumber AS signed) as pagenumber FROM (
    SELECT
    abbrevNames
    , IF(@prev = abbrevNames, @rows_per_abbrev:=@rows_per_abbrev + 1, @pagenr:=@pagenr + 1)
    , @prev:=abbrevNames
    , IF(@rows_per_abbrev % 250 = 0, @pagenr:=@pagenr + 1, @pagenr) AS pagenumber
    , IF(@rows_per_abbrev % 250 = 0, @rows_per_abbrev := 1, @rows_per_abbrev)
    FROM
    yourTable
    , (SELECT @pagenr:=0, @prev:=NULL, @rows_per_abbrev:=0) variables_initialization
    ORDER BY abbrevNames
) subquery_alias
```

UPDATE: I had misunderstood the question a bit. Now it should work

Comment: I should probably add that pagenumber values are all currently null

Comment: Corrected (I hope), please try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The query runs fine through all records, but the value for pagenumber shows as (Excluded) in the result set.

Comment: Please try again. Added a cast. I'm sure it's just an issue with your frontend.

Comment: Whoops... spoke too soon. It assigns page numbers OK but it allows unlimited (more than 250) page-numbers per unique abbrevName. Could you elaborate on what the code it doing? Specifically how is the @pagenr variable assigned? Thanks.

Comment: Edited version works perfectly, just need to figure out how to update table from results set now. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you really need to? If yes, you will have to use a (temporary) table, since you can't update and read from the same table at the same time. The other option would be to just make this a VIEW.

Comment: Yes these page numbers need to be stored in the same table as an existing utility depends on this. I will look into updating from a temporary table, thanks.